# How can I prove $Q(x,y,z)=x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}$ represents integer mod p?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-forms, sums-of-squares

p is an odd prime.

Clearly Q represents all squares modulo p and all integers divisible by p, so the problem is really just the nonsquares modulo p. I started by letting $t$ be the smallest nonsquare mod p that is not represented by Q. I deduced that $t-1$ and $t-2$ must also be nonsquares, but I failed to derive a contradiction.

On the other hand legendre's three squares theorem says all integers can be represented by Q over the integers  except those of the form $4^{n}(8k+7), n\in mathbb{N}, k\in mathbb{Z}$. But this doesn't mean numbers in that form cannot be represented in modulo p. For example $7\equiv 4^{2}+1+1 \mod[11]$. But I have no clue to prove that all numbers of the form  $4^{n}(8k+7)$ are necessarily represented by Q modulo p.

Comment: there is a simple counting argument that shows that just two squares are good enough for what you seem to be asking, given $n,$ we can solve $x^2 + y^2 \equiv n \pmod p$

Comment: Or, if you go your way, recall that the ratio of any two non-squares is a square modulo $p$, so if you represent a single non-square, you represent everything.

Answer (score 1):

As you note, the three squares theorem says (for example) that every integer of the form $8k+1$ is the sum of three squares.

On the other hand, for an odd prime $p$, it's easy to solve $8k+1\equiv t\pmod p$ for $k$, namely $k \equiv 8^{-1}(t-1) \pmod p$. Therefore any $t$ can be represented, modulo $p$, as the sum of three squares.